# Как создать динамический массив объектов?(не List)

Tags: java

Пытаюсь создать динамический массив объектов, но не выходит. Требует указать размерность, List или HashMap не подходят. Есть ли варианты сделать его динамическим или расширять добавляя элементы?

```
int n = 1;
SomeObject mainArray[] = new SomeObject[n];
mainArray[0]=new SomeObject("gp",2);
```

Comment: Почему `List` не подходит? Он внутри собственно массив использует и его пересоздаёт при добавлении с новым размером

Comment: Насколько я знаю изменять длину массивов в Java нельзя, поэтому скорее всего Вам придется создавать новый массив большего размера и переносить элементы из одного в другой. Грубо говоря, вы должны написать полный аналог класса ArrayList или Queue... ну или использовать уже написанное, это как хотите.

Comment: @GerzogTheBat вы можете открыть [исходный код ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) и там увидеть те самые массивы, динамичность которых обеспечивается копированием через Arrays.copyOf и System.arraycopy на минимальном уровне.

Comment: `Пытаюсь создать ..., но не выходит.` Так что не выходило-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну откройте класс List и перепешите нужные вам методы, либо унаследуйтесь и переопределите.

Если и это не подходит, то определите критические секции в коде и на них проверяйте размер массива, если он заполнен на 75% то удваиваете размер и все переносите.

Если не секрет, чем не угодили List и Set?

Comment: не подскажите, как написанный мной выше код реализовать, через List? он не подходил потому что я рассчитывал на то что в java, всё же можно более менее простым способ реализовать динамический массив)

Comment: @GerzogTheBat, не смысла самостоятельно реализовывать динамический массив. Используйте готовую реализацию - `ArrayList`. Пока вы не приведёте доводы против использования оного ваш вопрос выглядит как `Хочу переписать Java, т.к. мне не нравится ключевое слово import и я хочу заменить его на include`

Comment: @GerzogTheBat просто открываете класс ArrayList и переписываете, если вам очень хочется сдать свой динамический массив

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях я всегда использовал ArrayList.
Нет фиксированного размера и всегда можно добавить или удалить элемент.

Если я правильно понял вопрос.